# How to create custom commerce order states?

Tags: rules, commerce

I want to create custom order state's and in a view use a "button" or a "select list" to toggle those states.

For example I have view that display's a table of all orders that are marked completed.
I would like to add a "button" or "select list" to each row so that I can toggle the state for each order.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this module [Commerce Custom Order Status](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_custom_order_status) it can help you with custom statuses.

Comment: Someone with a higher reputation than me please vote this down. Commerce States are NOT commerce statuses. The hook solution below is the only approach until the day a dedicated module appears.

Comment: Same goes this is not a complete answer actually because this module simply adds a status see https://www.drupal.org/node/1816358 still an outstanding issue for this module unfortunately

Answer (score 10):

Two things there:

A. Define your custom order states with one of the Order info hooks.

1. [hook_commerce_order_state_info](http://www.drupalcommerce.org/developer-guide/core-architecture/info-hooks/order-info-hooks)
2. [hook_commerce_order_status_info](http://www.drupalcommerce.org/developer-guide/core-architecture/info-hooks/order-info-hooks)

B. Create a commerce_order based VBO view and add an operation to change the order state. It won't be a button on each row, just a checkbox or radio button, but you can batch update that way.

Alternatively, edit the order and set it's state on the edit form.

Answer (score 1):

I found the documentation on this to be unclear, so for reference, here's **an example of adding a status (not state) programmatically**.  This adds a new "credit card failure" status under the "Cancelled" state.

```
function mymodule_commerce_order_status_info() {
  $order_statuses['ccfail'] = array(
    'name' => 'ccfail',
    'title' => t('Credit card failure'),
    'state' => 'canceled',
  );

 return $order_statuses;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with the code in the previous example but this worked for me as a way to add a new status of 'Refunded' to the existing 'Canceled' State after the existing 'Canceled' status.

```
function mymodule_commerce_order_status_info_alter(&$order_statuses) {
    $order_statuses['refund'] = array(
            'name' => 'refund',
            'title' => t('Refunded'),
            'state' => 'canceled',
            'cart' => FALSE,
            'weight' => 10,
    );
}
```

Note that the 'cart' index is required and if you don't included you will get an undefined index error.